# ng-change com objeto dinâmico

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dinâmico

Bom dia, estou utilizando o angular 2 e estou com dificuldades em utilizar a propriedade  'ng-change' depois que gero dinamicamente o objeto abaixo:

```
<input type=text class="insert" id="input' + data.id + '"  ng-model="input" ng-change="myFunction()"  maxlength="48" autofocus/>
```

As propriedades do angular simplesmente não funciona, como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim,

mude o binding para`[ngModel]` e utilize o evento `(ngModelChange)`

```
<input type=text class="insert" id="input' + data.id + '"  [ngModel]="input" (ngModelChange)="myFunction($event)" maxlength="48" autofocus/>
```